# Configuration to Automatically Install .NET 4 Framework in VS 2010 Setup Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, installation

[I know how to include the .NET Framework 4 as a dependency to my installer Setup Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framework) in Visual Studio 2010. However, is there a configuration to set to make the installer check if the dependency is available, and then install .NET 4 on the machine when it isn't?

At the moment all it does is include the .NET Framework 4 installer in a separate folder in the "Release" output folder.

**UPDATE:**

1. I do have the .NET Framework 4 set as a launch condition.
2. I do have the .NET Framework 4 set as a precondition.
3. One thing I notice, in the launch conditions window, I cannot delete the current .NET Framework launch condition, and the option "Add .NET Framework Launch Condition" is greyed out.

Comment: Note that my problem is occurring when installing on windows xp. Not sure of the result on Windows 7.

Comment: Also note that the main executable I am trying to install is an unsigned assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an launch condition in addition to making a pre-requisite (as described in your link):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxyh2e6a.aspx

Comment: This hasn't solved the problem. Any other ideas? When I run the installer it is like it doesn't even do that check...

Comment: Is this an upgraded vdproj that used to be for 3.5? The upgrade process can be a bit buggy

Answer (score 0):

You need a prerequisite instead of a launch condition:

- in your setup project Launch Conditions Editor remove the .NET Framework launch condition
- right-click your setup project in Solution Explorer and select Properties
- click **Prerequisites** button in the shown property page
- make sure that the appropriate .NET Framework prerequisite is checked

Optionally, you can create your own [custom prerequisite](http://setupanddeployment.com/uncategorized/custom-prerequisite-visual-studio-setup-file/) instead of using the predefined one.

Launch conditions stop the install when not met. Prerequisites are packages which are automatically detected and installed before your main installation.

Comment: Although I may try different combinations of the above solutions.