# How to compile a program under windows vista that runs on windows 7 / VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I have created an application with VB 2010. My computer runs under Windows Vista. I created the .EXE file as well; simulated an installation and everything works fine. But when I try to install the application in a computer that runs under Windows 7, I get an error message and the application won't install. How can I get the application to run under Win7?

Comment: Can you post the error message? Is it because of a lack of the `.NET Framework`?

Comment: I can't right now. I didn't write it down. But my VB is .NET Framework and supposedly it automatically install the .NET Framework with the application. Or so I read... Sorry I cannot give you more details. I'm new in all this programming world and my knowledge is limited. could it be anything else?

Comment: The error message is the most important part, you should go and try it again and record the message. But unless you specifically wrote a part of the application *not* using `.NET`, then it won't install the framework for you. I would try downloading the `.NET Framework` on your Win7 PC and trying again.

Comment: And how can I verify if my VB is or is not compiling applications that are able to install the framework?

Comment: [This question may help you with that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8073399/451590).

Comment: No problem- I have transposed our comment stream to an answer. If it helped you, remember to "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

You want to be sure you have the `.NET` Framework installed on the PC, since VB.NET (and C#, etc.) use the .NET Framework to interact with the CLR, which is not included with Windows by default.

You can either set-up your installer to [install the .NET Framework on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8073399/451590) or [download the framework separately](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718).

Comment: I always find it easy on client machines to run windows update to get the updated .NET frameworks.

Comment: +1 The .Net framework is an [optional part of Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx). It might need to be installed.