# Can we create an installer which first installs .Net 2.0 (not from internet) and then installs my software?

Tags: c#, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make an Installation program for C# applications and include .NET Framework installer into the setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framework)

Can we make an installer of an application which is .net 2.0+application.
Mean that it first install .net 2.0 (not from internet but from itself) and than install my software.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733).

Comment: Erm... I think you'd agree that posting bare links should be done in comments (even ignoring the fact that this is an obvious dupe). Cheers!

Comment: @sehe, no, we don't agree. Posting links towards articles that provide solution to the question is normal. In cases where those links point towards reliable sites (such as microsoft.com) which we can expect will be online for rather long time, it is also normal not to copy-paste the contents of the link in the answer. On the other hand I agree about the dupe. I should have searched first. Voting to close as duplicate now.

Comment: Mmm. The community opion seems to be well established: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers. Maybe I'll re-read that just to update my opinion :) Cheers

Comment: @sehe, I post links all the time and this is the first time I get downvoted for this. Unfortunately I don't visit meta and don't know what exactly is the community's opinion about that. I have built my own opinion about SO and the way to answer questions. I guess I will have to read this article on meta and try to respect the well established practices. Thanks for pointing me out this article.

Comment: Honestly, I don't pay meta much attention. But I have seen `link-posting` being downvoted, actively commented on and even flagged on numerous (dozens) of times. Some of the time people would link to that meta post (and others) which is how I formed/adjusted opinion :). (Personally I hate it when I have taken the time to write an write a nice, targeted, answer, and someone just 'drive-by-posts-a-link'. That doesn't motivate contributers to make SO prime resource of quality answers)