# Add .Net Framework 4.0 into setup project

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make an Installation program for C# applications and include .NET Framework installer into the setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framework)

I have windows application into .net framework 4.0, I want to add .net framework 4.0 into setup file..

I have added it using Prerequisites,but when i start to download it it required internet connection. and file is about 250 MB

is it possible  that when i start to install application, it also install .net framework automatically ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framework try this.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the Visual Studio installer setup project, go to the Setup Projects Properties and click the Prerequisites button, you then need to select your required framework([3.5 does not work out of the Box look at section 2.3.1.1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm) ). Then you select `Download prerequisites from the same location as my application`. This will include the Framework as part of your Setup.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work without actually making the prerequisites available in the bootstrapper directory.

Comment: @MARK Can you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873800/how-to-check-any-condition-before-installation-process-takes-place . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,by adding .net framework setup in your own setup and start .net framework setup through process if .net setup not installed on client machine.