# How to check any condition before installation process takes place?

Tags: c#, .net, installation, setup-deployment

I am making a setup of windows application. In setup process i added a screen using user interface dialog properties and taking some input from user and want to put condition like this:

```
if(value_is_correct)
{ 
   Continue_setup;
}
else
{
   Rollback_setup;
}
```

Somehow my objective is complete but I want to rearrange the steps of process :

1. I ask user to enter value(password)
2. User clicks on next
3. Next dialog screen appears, Setup process get started and in between that process it shows that password is wrong and it again Rollbacks the setup.

These images shows the process clearly:

[image: asking password]

[image: showing wrong password error]

My question is :How to check the condition on click of Next button of Password form.(First Image). It should not start the installation process.

Please provide any solution or any useful link. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I see an issue. You're asking for a conditional.. yet you've provided one. What is the exact issue you're having implementing this?

Comment: I don't want anyone to install this who doesn't have license key of product, that's why need to check it before installation.

Comment: What tool are you using to author your setup project?

Comment: i am creating setup using visual studio 2010 itself.