# How to Create Installer for my Project

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

Hi guys i have a c# project that i want to create an installer.I want the installer to do the following:

- Copy all the files that my application is using to a user chosen path (copy the files to the chosen path).
- Ask for a specific Path(my c# program requires Google Drive Application to be installed and need its path)
- Create Folders and Text files in that  Path.

Please help me guys thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/6090929/2458971

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! I recommend you take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and head back when you have a specific programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

Project Setup & Install was dropped after Visual Studio 2010. You'll either have to go the WiX route, or if you have Visual Studio 2013, you can create an InstallShield Limited project. There are several alternatives as well, just do a search.

Here's a link to a page that gives a video walkthrough of how to create an application installer with InstallShield Limited from Visual Studio 2013:

http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio