# how to create ClickOnce type setup in Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, setup-project

Please tell me how to Deploy application, which installs all it's dependencies like .net framework, MSSQL, etc. itself.

I have added all the dependencies in my setup Project, but when I install my setup it show message like **.net Framework 4.0 is not installed. Download it from Microsoft's Website and then Install**

It's not installing dependency which is in setup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make an Installation program for C# applications and include .NET Framework installer into the setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framework)

Comment: @Lars Thanks.! I was looking from Long time......