# How can create an installer from my Application C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I would like to create a wizard which will create an installer in C#. How can I do that? Please help.. I need to pack some executable files and a mdb database to the application creator. The database is dynamically generated. So the usual setup project won't work.

Comment: probably u need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framework

Comment: @SundarRajan How do you create the database ?

Comment: As an access file. The application works based on the database file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a more flexible (custom) installer, I recommend using WiX

you can start from [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html)

Download WiX from [here](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/99514)

or

The faster (typical) way but not flexible (custom) is:

> new Project -> Other Project types -> Setup and Deployment

Comment: I need to pack some files from a wizard. WiX supports that?

Comment: Yes, it does, As I said WiX is very flexible.

Comment: You can start downloading WiX from here:
http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/99514

Comment: Don't forget, WiX has a VS plugin and some handy helpers like burn. Here is a complete tutorial to create an installer with imho the most common tasks: http://atlasteit.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/how-to-get-yourself-a-microsoft-isv-certification/

Comment: @atlaste the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I use advanced Installer. It is not free software but It is pretty good and extremly easy to use. Check if it meets your requirement or not

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/