# how can i attach .NET Framework 4.5 so Setup file

Tags: c#, setup-deployment

I want to attach .NET Framework 4.5 to setup file . i check Microsoft.Net Framework 4.5 (X86 and X64) in prerequisites window.

But it says :
You must download file `'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'` for item `'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)'` to your local machine. For more information, see [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883).

I downloaded `.NET Framework 4.5`. & named it "dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe" and put it in Debug folder. But it says this error again.

I browsed [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883) . As you see it says about `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages...` . But i did not seen `DotNetFX45` folder there.

Comment: Take a look of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6090929. This will helpful for you...

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to choose that option.

[image]