# Using Visual Studio Installer on VS2013 Professional for C# WinForms app. create Installation with .NET Framework installation included

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, installation

I have a WinForms C# Application I've created.
I want to create Install file which include installation of .Net Framework 4.5 if it is not installed on the computer yet.
I've downloaded and installed the Visual Studio Installer and tried to follow the steps shown in [Make an Installation program for C# applications and include .NET Framework installer into the setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framework) but instead the 3rd. step at the example i am requested to provide the files to be installed and there is no option to instruct the installation to install .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Installer project need to be created in the solution where the application for deployment is found, otherwise (when creating new independent project it will skip this step).