# Ideal Launch Time of Windows Desktop Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, desktop-application

What is the ideal/acceptable load time of a windows desktop software that does not frustrate the user and make him to use an alternative.Is 4 seconds acceptable ? I find that embedding 3RD party dlls pushes the load time to 4 seconds .. If i just copy the dlls the launch time can be reduced to 3 seconds or 2.XX seconds.

I use this these dlls for skinning the winforms application.I personally don't like to keep these exposed to prevent competitors from finding out what I use.

Comment: Ideal? That would be zero seconds...

Comment: Rather than spending time worrying about your competitors (if they exist) copying your idea (to use a 3rd party, who'd have ever thought?), why not spend time working on things your *customers* would value?

Comment: And what I really don't understand here is a combination of a belief you have a USP... that's achieved using 3rd party tooling, unless you have an exclusive arrangement with that 3rd party?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for your input.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal time is 0 sec, but depending on the application, it is hard to reach. An application takes as long as it needs (Have look at Visual Studio for example, when opening a project I go to the coffee machine).

I wouldn't embbed the dll. It is not worth the cost, especialy you (or the competitor) can see them anyway with assembly explorers like [dotPeak](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

For distribution, you would create a [setup wizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6090913/2441442), so the user wouldn't see them too.

Comment: I use obfuscation and some packer to protect the exe.. so dotPeak won't work.But if I bundle the dll, the load time increases.

Comment: Even then, expecting your competitors are developers, it is not that hard to find third party libaries. In my opinion, 2 seconds more loadtime is worse then security by obscurity. @techno