# How to create Setup.exe

Tags: c#, google-chrome, installation, setup-deployment, bootstrapper

I have a console application called app.exe. I need to create Setup.exe so that, if we download and run the Setup.exe it should download the app.exe and install. It should be something like chrome. If we download ChromeSetup.exe and run it, it downloads and installs the actual chrome browser in the PC. How to do that.(Preferably in c#)

Comment: Perhaps with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make an Installation program for C# applications and include .NET Framework installer into the setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090913/make-an-installation-program-for-c-sharp-applications-and-include-net-framework)

Comment: @JustinEzequiel, This is not the one i was looking for.

Comment: @jalsh, that wraps the installer file to app.exe. I need an executable file like Setup.exe so that, by downloading and running that setup.exe, the Setup.exe should download and install the app.exe by itself. just like ChromeSetup.exe .

Comment: Maybe you can try `ClickOnce`. For the steps, you can refer to https://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/how-to-use-clickonce-to-deploy-your-applications.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if that is what you are looking for:

```
1. Click on solution and then Properties.
2. Click on Publish and then Prerequisites.
3. Click on 'Create setup program'
```

Comment: No, this is not the one i was looking for.