# vb.net How do I install an application on a standalone laptop?

Tags: vb.net, publish

I created a small application in VB.NET which I published. I want to install it on a standalone laptop without internet access. The code is trying to download files so the installation doesn't work.

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 1 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.1.1 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Release' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read integer value 394806
Setting value '394806 {int}' for property 'DotNetFull_Release'
Reading value 'v4' of registry key 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\OS Integration'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNetFull_OSIntegrated'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNetFull_Release] = 394806 {int}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThan' on property 'DotNetFull_Release' and value '461808': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '6.1.0': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
EULA for components 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\SECTIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD3FED.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\SECTIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD3FED.tmp\"
(31-3-2021 10:56:50) Downloading 'DotNetFX472\NDP472-KB4054531-Web.exe' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=863262&clcid=0x409' to 'C:\Users\SECTIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD3FED.tmp\'
Download completed at 31-3-2021 10:56:50
Downloading failed with HRESULT=-2146697211
```

Is there a way to publish an application so it includes all I need on the destination pc?

Comment: Ship the prerequisites with your app and configure the installer to get them from the installation dir. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090929/14171304).

Comment: @dr.null so basically I just create a new project which includes all programs I need to be installed on my laptop. Then I install that on my laptop and my original program will be able to work?

Comment: Your app will run if all the prerequisites exist in the target machine. The target .NET Framework, libraries if any, resources ...etc. Just follow the steps in the referred link and your app will work. No problem. [Another](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-setup-and-deployment-projects-in-vs-net/) example.