# i wanna create a new file extension like "prproj"primiere pro in c# what should i do?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, file, format

```
        string ext = ".ext";
        RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(ext);
        MessageBox.Show(exePath);
        key.SetValue("", "My Project");
        key.Close();

        key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(ext + "\\Shell\\Open\\command");
        //key = key.CreateSubKey("command");

        key.SetValue("", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\" \"%L\"");
        key.Close();

        key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(ext + "\\DefaultIcon");
        key.SetValue("", Application.StartupPath + "\\icon.ico");
        key.Close();
```

i wanna create a new file extension like "prproj" primiere pro in c#,for example you save that file and you wanna open it again and when you clicked at file, it will be opened in your application and  also, i want to know how to give a icon file to that file?

please help!

Comment: should i use this code?

Comment: This code doesn't look to bad. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You can examine the registery keys of other file extensions to learn how that works.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/customizing-file-types-bumper)?

Comment: to be honest i dont know what should i do, should i use xml and if i need to use it, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Setup Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090929/6694923), in it you can change the parameter that is responsible for the file extension belonging to your program.

[image]

Comment: i dont have this panels you have, how did you do that ?

Comment: @mahdi-noroozi, in the _Solution Explorer_, you need to select (make active) the project created using the **Setup Wizard**. After that, you will have the wizard project management buttons on the top panel.